# Elements of a list

Tags: python-2.7

Hi please how can I add other elements ie z[i], in z in the last line of this code

```
z = [2,3,4,5]
my_file.write('%s' % j + 'a' + ':' + str(z[0]) + ',')#z[0] = first element in z
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `join`, or a loop.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smth like that?

```
z = [2,3,4,5]
with open("output.txt", 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write('a: %s' % ', '.join([str(i) for i in z]))
```

output.txt:

```
a: 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: thanks @aspect for your reply, I tried the iter() method as well and it worked fine too